# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toNumber' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Cannot read property 'toNumber' of undefined?

**Error message**

> 1) Contract: DappTokenSale
>          ends token sale:
>        TypeError: Cannot read property 'toNumber' of undefined
>         at test/DappTokenSale.js:85:28
>         at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

**Code**

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require('./DappToken.sol');
var DappTokenSale = artifacts.require('./DappTokenSale.sol');

contract('DappTokenSale', function(accounts) {
var tokenInstance;
var tokenSaleInstance;
var admin = accounts[0];
var buyer = accounts[1];
var tokenPrice = 1000000000000000; // in wei
var tokensAvailable = 750000;
var numberOfTokens;

it('initializes the contract with the correct values', function() {
return DappTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  tokenSaleInstance = instance;
  return tokenSaleInstance.address
}).then(function(address) {
  assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, 'has contract address');
  return tokenSaleInstance.tokenContract();
}).then(function(address) {
  assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, 'has token contract address');
  return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
}).then(function(price) {
  assert.equal(price, tokenPrice, 'token price is correct');
});
});

it('facilitates token buying', function() {
return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  // Grab token instance first
  tokenInstance = instance;
  return DappTokenSale.deployed();
}).then(function(instance) {
  // Then grab token sale instance
  tokenSaleInstance = instance;
  // Provision 75% of all tokens to the token sale
  return tokenInstance.transfer(tokenSaleInstance.address, tokensAvailable, { from: admin })
}).then(function(receipt) {
  numberOfTokens = 10;
  return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens * tokenPrice })
}).then(function(receipt) {
  assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
  assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Sell', 'should be the "Sell" event');
  assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._buyer, buyer, 'logs the account that purchased the tokens');
  assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._amount, numberOfTokens, 'logs the number of tokens purchased');
  return tokenSaleInstance.tokensSold();
}).then(function(amount) {
  assert.equal(amount.toNumber(), numberOfTokens, 'increments the number of tokens sold');
  return tokenInstance.balanceOf(buyer);
}).then(function(balance) {
  assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), numberOfTokens);
  return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
}).then(function(balance) {
  assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), tokensAvailable - numberOfTokens);
  // Try to buy tokens different from the ether value
  return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: 1 });
}).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
  assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'msg.value must equal number of tokens in wei');
  return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(800000, { from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens * tokenPrice })
}).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
  assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'cannot purchase more tokens than available');
});
});

it('ends token sale', function() {
return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  // Grab token instance first
  tokenInstance = instance;
  return DappTokenSale.deployed();
}).then(function(instance) {
  // Then grab token sale instance
  tokenSaleInstance = instance;
  // Try to end sale from account other than the admin
  return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: buyer });
}).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
  assert(error.message.indexOf('revert' >= 0, 'must be admin to end sale'));
  // End sale as admin
  return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: admin });
}).then(function(receipt) {
  return tokenInstance.balanceOf(admin);
}).then(function(balance) {
  assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 999990, 'returns all unsold dapp tokens to admin');
  // Check that the contract has no balance
  }).then(function(price) {
    assert.equal(price.toNumber(), 0, 'token price was reset');
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be here:

```js
.then(function(balance) {
   assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 999990, 'returns all unsold dapp tokens to admin');
   // Check that the contract has no balance
}).then(function(price) {
   assert.equal(price.toNumber(), 0, 'token price was reset');
});
```

There's no return value from that first function, so of course `price` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks Smarx!


How would you write that return value?

Comment: I have no idea. There's no mention of a "price" anywhere in your code, so I don't know what value you're trying to test.

Answer (score 1):

```
 .then((balance) => {
        assert.equal(
          balance.toNumber(),
          999990,
          "balance left with admin after ending sale"
        );
        return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
      })
      .then((balance) => {
        assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 0, "contract has been reset");
      });
```